# Ajax call doesn't work when debug="false" (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I resolve my problem?
When I call

> jQuery.ajax(my_ajax_request); or $.ajax(my_ajax_request);

with debug="true" it works correctly and doesn't work if debug="false"

P.S. I'm using bundles

Upd.:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Comment: Have you checked the page for any missing files, when debug mode is changed?

Comment: `<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=somehashcode"></script>`

Comment: In browser, Open developer tools. Do you see any errors?

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'`  `jQuery' is undefined`  `The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

Comment: Now, I am sure that your bundle configurations are not correct. Please post the code to check further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118079/discussion-between-drake-and-vivek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundle configurations seems correct. When `debug="false"` is used, the min version of libraries is used. You can also use CDN for the same. For debugging the problem, You should check these:

1. Check for Jquery and related libraries versions for any compatibility issues. Not all packages are compatible with each other.
2. [Read Official post about bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for more details.

Thanks